# Flash Builder 4.6: Testing gestures without the device

Tags: android, apache-flex, mobile, flash-builder, emulation

I'm new at developing a Flex app for mobile,**I just need to know is there any way to test/debug gestures like swipe on the android emulator that comes with Flash Builder 4.6**.

I saw people using the official Android Emulator for testing, are there other quicker alternatives? As my application relyes on swiping views, each time I want to test it I need to export it and open it in the other emulator without the debug capacity.

Thanks!

Comment: Forgo emulators and test right on a device. W/ Android is it very easy from Flash Builder.  Testing mobile apps on PC emulators is like testing IE6 JavaSCript on Firefox; just not very effective use of your time.

Answer (score 0):

No, but if you are on Mac you can use the iOS Simulator which has this feature. You will also need Flash Builder 4.7 to use the iOS Simulator.

Comment: Actually, I need a solution for Android.